# How can I put the buttons in the last order

Tags: javascript, html

this question is so complicated.. pls help..

So I have 2 buttons you can see in the 1. Picture. I want the buttons after reloading the page, to be in the same order as I sorted it.

Imported scripts:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.1/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/muuri/0.5.3/muuri.min.js"></script>
```

[sorted by HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxpY8.png)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <a>
        <div class="card-primary" style="width-min: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Test</h5>
                <p class="card-text">asdasd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a>
        <div class="card-info" style="width-min: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">asd</h5>
                <p class="card-text">asd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[sorted by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSpmZ.png)

(WITH Muuri)

```
const grid = new Muuri(".grid", {
    dragEnabled: false
});
```

**QUESTION:**

I want when the page reloaded, that the Buttons goes in the right order from *my last time sorted order*.

(otherwise the HTML CODE will bring the buttons in the standart order... thats the problem)

I tried many stuff like lists and updated an DATABASE in sql but nothing seems to work, so does anyone can Help me with a tip or a little code? That would be very very nice!

Comment: You can try storing the order in `location.hash` and keeping it up-to-date and restoring the order upon page load.

Comment: Loading the order is not difficult, that's what I wanted to do with SQL but it's how the script takes the order I have "saved" and sort of takes it over

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store the order to the `local storage` every time a change of order happens, then when the page reloads, you first check the `local storage` for any preset order.

I would also suggest you give some identifier attribute to every card so that it can be accessed easily rather than the need to identify them by the inner text.

```
document.querySelector('the-sort-button').addEventListener('toggle-or-smth', () => {
  let order = getCardsOrder();
  localStorage.setItem("cardOrder", order);
});
```

Now on the beginning of the script you need to check for previous order.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let order = localStorage.getItem("cardOrder");
  if (order !== null) setCardsOrder(order);
});
```

The implementation of `getCardsOrder` and `setCardsOrder` is pretty vague for me as I am not familiar with the plugin you are using, but I hope this gives you a general guideline.

Comment: mhhh.. difficult